# ¿Que hacer en el caso de una respuesta no aceptada por un nuevo usuario?

Tags: soporte, usuarios-nuevos, respuesta-aceptada

Hay muchas veces que un nuevo usuario edita el titulo de una respuesta como `[RESPONDIDA]`, o da las gracias en un comentario indicando que se ha solucionado el problema pero no acepta la respuesta usando la marca de *check*.

**Que hacer en estos casos?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Para estos casos, voy a adaptar una de mis [respuestas de referencia](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251298/3850595) en MetaStackOverflow.

---

Si el usuario **nunca ha aceptado una respuesta** y ha agradecido via comentario indicando que le ha solucionado su problema, escribiria algo asi:

> Hola @usuario12345 si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto su problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/25) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a ti y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.

(markdown del comentario):

`Hola @usuario12345 si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto su problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a tí y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.`

Eso si, con excepciones, porque si el usuario **ha aceptado una respuesta antes**, entonces es consciente de cómo funciona el sistema. Si se comenta en esta situación parecerá como si estuvieras rogando por la reputación o presionando a un usuario de reputación inferior a aceptar la respuesta. Y ninguno de estos casos está bien visto por la comunidad.

Comment: Aunque un usuario haya aceptado otras respuestas. Si esta respuesta en concreto ha sido agradecida por el usuario que hizo la pregunta indicando que le resolvió el problema y no ha aceptado ninguna me parece bien recordarlo. Puede ser que se le haya olvidado. Si a mi se me hubiese olvidado aceptar una respuesta de la que he dicho que me ha solucionado mi pregunta no solo no me molestaría sino que agradecería que me lo recordasen.

Comment: Puede ser @JoseAntonio, pero creo que en esos casos como mínimo es mejor esperar un poco. Yo personalmente voy haciendo un repaso periódicamente y acepto las que falten (ahora mismo tengo un par pendientes) pero igualmente creo que tanto tu postura como la mía son correctas siempre y cuando se trate a los nuevos con respeto

Comment: completamente de acuerdo.

Comment: Hay casos en que he visto muy buenas respuestas que resuelven totalmente la pregunta, pero el error del usuario era en realidad otro y por tanto no valora la respuesta o bien usuarios que preguntan y nunca regresan a ver las respuestas. Creo que también habría que normar este hecho ya que 'ensucian' un poco la comunidad.

Comment: Estaría bueno si este tipo de respuestas pudieran ser hechas de manera automática (¿o quizás incluso enviadas al email?), ciertamente queda feo cuando haces el comentario porque suena a que estás pidiendo que se acepte la respuesta y no es eso.