# ¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?

Tags: soporte, faq, respuesta, respuesta-propia, respuesta-aceptada

Pregunta original: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/182862)

- ¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?
- ¿Cuándo debería hacerlo?
- ¿Por qué no puedo aceptar mis propias respuestas de inmediato?
- ¿Qué respuesta debería aceptar?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54044/discussion-on-question-by-luiggi-mendoza-como-funciona-la-aceptacion-de-respues). Asimismo es importante mantener una conversacion respetuosa.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Adaptado de: [How does accepting an answer work? (respuesta)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/182862)*

Aceptar una respuesta: ¿cómo funciona?

Aceptar una respuesta es importante porque así su autor resulta premiado tanto por resolver tu problema como por informar a otros de que tu problema está resuelto.

- Se puede seleccionar cualquier respuesta como la respuesta "aceptada" en las preguntas que has respondido. Solo una respuesta a la vez puede ser la "aceptada".
- Existe un breve periodo de tiempo ([15 minutos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50697/182862)) inmediatamente después de publicar la pregunta durante el cual no se puede aceptar una respuesta.
- Para marcar una respuesta como aceptada, haz click en el check al costado de la respuesta para cambiarla de vacía a verde (mira la captura de pantalla abajo).
- Se puede cambiar cuál es la respuesta aceptada, o simplemente "desaceptar" la respuesta, en cualquier momento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si aceptas:

- *la respuesta de otra persona*: obtendrás **+2** de reputación y el autor de la respuesta obtendrá **+15** de reputación.
- *tu propia respuesta*: no se concede reputación y la respuesta no se situará en la parte superior de la lista de respuestas. Esto no puede ser hecho antes de que hayan pasado 48 horas desde que se publicó la pregunta.
- *una respuesta [wiki de comunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/community-wiki/info)*: no se concede reputación.

**¿Qué respuesta debería escoger?**

- No dudes en aceptar una respuesta que está bien redactada, sugiere una buena práctica y funciona para ti.
- En caso contrario, incluso si hay respuestas que son *suficientemente buenas* pero no estás completamente satisfecho, podrías esperar de 24 a 48 horas para dar la oportunidad a otras personas de proveer una mejor respuesta. Es poco probable que una pregunta con una respuesta aceptada reciba más atención, a diferencia de una pregunta que no tiene una respuesta aceptada.
- Asegúrate de que además de funcionar para ti, la respuesta es realmente una buena práctica. Algunas veces después de que una respuesta es aceptada, puede publicarse otra que muestra que la respuesta anterior era, de hecho, un mal hack.
- **En resumen, deberías aceptar la respuesta que encuentres como la más útil para ti, personalmente.**

**Votos a favor**

- Si una respuesta te ha ayudado a resolver tu problema y la aceptas, deberías considerar votarla a favor.
- Si otras respuestas también han sido útiles, también puedes votarlas a favor.
- Puedes votar a favor si has obtenido el privilegio [voto a favor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), otorgado con 15 puntos de reputación.

**¿Qué debería hacer si ninguna de las respuestas es adecuada?**

- Vuelve a leer tu pregunta críticamente y cerciórate de que queda claro cuál es el problema y cuál es la pregunta específica. Podrías querer resaltar una oración al final para asegurarte de que está claro qué es lo que se pregunta.
- Vuelve a leer las respuestas. Considera aceptar la mejor de las respuestas del grupo, incluso si ninguna de ellas es exactamente lo que se necesita.
- Espera unos días después de preguntar, y luego edita tu pregunta con lo que hayas aprendido desde que la publicaste - quizás la información adicional ayudará a los demás a ayudarte. Esto también tendrá el efecto de traer tu pregunta a la parte superior de la página de inicio, donde ojos frescos la verán.
- Si tienes más de 75 puntos de reputación, puedes iniciar una recompensa cuando hayan pasado dos días desde la publicación de la pregunta en caso que aún no hayas aceptado ninguna respuesta. Esto pondrá tu pregunta en la [lista de preguntas destacadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) y la hará más visible. Una recompensa también añadirá un incentivo para que la gente responda tu pregunta.
- Al final resolverás el problema o encontrarás una solución alternativa (que puedes ser "Esto no funcionará, así que esto es lo que hice en su lugar"). Por favor, añade una respuesta con esta información y acepta tu propia respuesta, así otros con la misma pregunta podrán ver el camino que finalmente seguiste.