# Preguntas sin respuesta elegida y/o puntos asignados

Tags: discusión

Pues bien, en el poco tiempo que llevo en SO en Español he detectado que muchas preguntas (Muy interesantes en su mayoría) han sido digamos "olvidadas" por el usuario que la o las formulo, y me refiero por "olvidadas" a que estas preguntas (gran parte de ellas) si fueron debidamente respondidas, no solo por una sola vez, pueden tener varias respuestas, pero carecen tanto de puntos y lo mas grave es que carecen de **respuesta elegida**.

He notado de igual forma que estos usuarios siguen formulando mas preguntas y como ya comente dejan olvidadas las anteriores, no se cual pueda ser la razón, pero si noto que estas preguntas fueron atendidas y pues bien hubo algún usuario que tomo su tiempo y dedicación en responder, no creo justo que simplemente la respuesta se quede abierta, cuando hay respuestas correctas.

¿Cual es el procedimiento a dicha situación?

---

**Edito por sugerencia:**

No solo me refiero a preguntas donde el usuario a referido que su pregunta fue resuelta, también me refiero aquellas preguntas donde el usuario simplemente no contesto y al revisar su perfil te das cuenta que su ultimo acceso fue hace no mas de 5 minutos.

Comment: En los sitios de Stack Exchange las buenas preguntas se quedan abiertas aún y cuando tenga una respuesta aceptada. Sólo se cierran las preguntas que no cumplen los lineamientos de publicación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siempre que puedas, pon un comentario al usuario en alguna de sus preguntas con un mensaje similar a este (puedes seleccionar la opción *editar* para que solo copies el texto con el enlace):

> Hola @<usuario>. Por favor no olvides de marcar la respuesta que más te ayudó como respuesta aceptada. Sigue las instrucciones indicadas aquí: [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/227).

La pregunta y su respuesta explican cómo aceptar las respuestas. Más allá de eso, no podemos hacer más para que acepten las respuestas.

Adicional a esto, cabe resaltar que lo principal en las respuestas no es que se marque como aceptada, sino ver el apoyo que da la comunidad hacia las respuestas. Ese apoyo se ve en los votos a favor, los cuales indican que la respuesta es útil. Hay casos en SO y en SOes donde la respuesta aceptada no es la más votada por diversos factores:

- Puede que surja un cambio de versión de la tecnología utilizada y la solución expuesta en la respuesta aceptada no aplique para futuras versiones.
- Puede que haya una respuesta que explique de manera simple una forma de solución, luego el usuario que publicó la pregunta se dio de baja del sitio (por motivos que no conocemos) o simplemente deja de acceder con su cuenta. Después, otro usuario encuentra la pregunta y provee una respuesta más elaborada que recibe más votos que la respuesta aceptada.