# Cambiar tilde y enlace en "Como aceptar una respuesta" de la sección de ayuda "¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?"

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

En [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) detalla el proceso de revisar respuestas y, según cómo, aceptar alguna.

Hay una sección que dice:

> Como aceptar una respuesta:
>
> - Escoge una respuesta que pienses que tenga la mejor solución a tu problema.
>
> ...

Pues bien, el texto *Como aceptar una respuesta* tiene dos fallos actualmente.

- *Como* debe llevar tilde, pues se trata de un adverbio interrogativo: *Cómo aceptar...*
- El enlace apunta ahora mismo a la pregunta de Meta Stack Exchange [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/209901). Sin embargo, esta fue traducida hace un tiempo por Luiggi en [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/83), por lo que sería útil cambiar el enlace para que apunte a esta versión en castellano y así facilitar su comprensión por parte de todos.