# ¿Cuál es el significado de los colores que se utilizan en las preguntas de Stack Overflow?

Tags: soporte, interfaz-de-usuario, diseño

1. ¿Qué significa el color verde en las respuestas?
2. ¿Qué significa cuando las respuesta no tienen ese color verde?
3. ¿Qué significa cuando las preguntas están sombreadas con un color rojizo?

[image: Captura de pantalla]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

En lo referido a los colores en el contador de respuestas de cada pregunta:

- **Texto negro sobre fondo blanco**: pregunta sin ninguna respuesta.

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- **Texto y borde verde sobre fondo blanco**: pregunta con al menos una respuesta pero el usuario que realizó la pregunta no ha [marcado como aceptada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) ninguna.

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- **Texto blanco sobre fondo verde**: pregunta con al menos una respuesta y el usuario que realizó la pregunta ha marcado alguna de ellas como aceptada.

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto a al fondo y formato de las preguntas en si en la lista de preguntas, tenemos dos situaciones (además del fondo blanco normal):

- **Fondo de color [#fffbec](https://www.google.es/search?q=%23fffbec&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=MQmaWYLWGJeE4gTCnZ2ABQ)** ¿crema, floral white, salmón, amarillo deslucido...? XD: Indica que al menos una de las etiquetas que tienes en tu lista de ***Etiquetas favoritas*** está presente en la pregunta.

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

  Si la lista de preguntas es el resultado de una búsqueda/filtro por etiqueta, las preguntas con estas etiquetas no serán destacadas aunque estén en la lista de favoritas, a no ser que al menos otra etiqueta no incluida en la búsqueda y presente en la lista de favoritas esté presente en la pregunta. Es decir, cuando se hace una búsqueda las etiquetas incluidas en ésta no son tenidas en cuenta a la hora de resaltar las preguntas. Si esto no fuera así, todas las preguntas de la búsqueda estarían resaltadas.
- **Pregunta con colores difuminados (oscurecidas)**: indica que esa pregunta contiene alguna de las etiquetas que tienes en tu lista de ***Etiquetas ignoradas***.

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

  Esto se puede configurar para que se muestren así, o para que directamente se oculten, en las preferencias de nuestro perfil:

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No sabía lo de ignoradas, nunca he usado esa opción, ni lo de que si había varias favoritas tenían que coincidir 2 etiquetas, ¿esa información está recogida en algún sitio?

Answer (score 2):

Cuando el recuadro de las respuestas tiene un borde verde significa que hay alguna respuesta, si todo el recuadro es verde es porque hay una respuesta aceptada. Las preguntas que aparecen resaltadas en amarillo (tú dices rojizo pero supongo que nos referimos a lo mismo) tienen alguna etiqueta que hayas marcado como favorita.

Comment: es mas naranja, que rojo o amarillo (mi esposa dice que es salmon).. podemos discutirlo eternamente..

Comment: @gbianchi Cada uno puede apreciar el color de maneras distintas y dependerá de monitor en el que lo veamos también pero hay algo objetivo en esto: el color en RGB es `255, 251, 236` el rojo y el verde tienen casi los mismos valores así que podíamos decir que es prácticamente amarillo; si lo convertimos a CMYK tenemos `0%, 1.6%, 7.5%, 0%` el porcentaje de amarillo es claramente superior al magenta. El color salmón tiene mucho mas rojo en comparación.

Comment: En mi monitor viejo casi ni se distingue sobre el fondo por eso le cambie el estilo con [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=es) para que el color sea `#ffe485`