# ¿Cómo puedo cerrar una pregunta con una respuesta favorable?

Tags: soporte

Cuando indico que una respuesta satisface mi pregunta ¿Cómo puedo indicar que esa pregunta ha sido respondida y no aceptar mas respuestas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En este sitio y los demás de la red de Stack Exchange las buenas preguntas no se cierran cuando reciben una buena respuesta, se cierran las malas preguntas y las que están fuera de los temas a tratar.

Cuando se recibe una buena respuesta, el autor de la pregunta puede aceptarla pero no puede bloquear el que se sigan publicando nuevas respuestas. Cuando una pregunta ha sido cerrada por lo mencionado anteriormente, es entonces que no se pueden publicar nuevas respuestas.

Si no lo has hecho aún lee:

- Artículo de ayuda: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
- FAQ: [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/65)

Answer (score 3):

En la excelente respuesta de Rubén tienes el caso normal.

Pero sí hay situaciones en que es necesario restrigir las respuestas. Incluso si hablamos de una buena pregunta con una buena respuesta.

A veces una pregunta atrae mucho la atención y recibe muchas respuestas de muy baja calidad de usuarios nuevos. En este caso se puede [proteger](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). Esto no la cierra del todo, solo la cierra a usuarios muy noveles.

Hace falta 15000 de reputación o ser moderador con diamante para proteger. Si crees que alguna pregunta necesita ser protegia puedes pasarte por el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol), quizás haya alguien que pueda hacerlo. Si está de acuerdo contigo. Si no encuentras a nadie puedes marcarla para atención de moderador.

> #### ¿Qué son las preguntas protegidas?
>
> Una pregunta protegida no admite respuestas por parte de usuarios
> anónimos o muy recientes.
>
> Las preguntas deberían ser protegidas cuando consiguen una gran
> cantidad de visitas y los novatos publican respuestas del tipo "¡Yo
> también!", "¡Gracias!" y posiblemente incluso no-respuestas tipo spam.
>
> #### ¿Qué preguntas pueden ser protegidas?
>
> Cualquier pregunta con al menos un día de antigüedad puede ser
> protegida y desprotegida por los usuarios que tengan este privilegio,
> siempre que la pregunta haya obtenido al menos una respuesta de un
> usuario con menos de 10 puntos de reputación (estos usuarios no podrán
> publicar más respuestas una vez que la pregunta haya sido protegida).

Comment: En aras de la completitud otro caso a considerar mencionar es el de los "[locked post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts)" :)